# How to enable the map unit function in "Sphere_Miller_Cylindrical" CRS in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, labeling

I am making  world maps, for varying purposes, and one of the requirements is to label each country with her name.
Normally I used the map map unit function in order to adjust the labels size to the map scale.
This time I was asked to use the "Sphere_Miller_Cylindrical" CRS, not the regular "WGS_84" CRS, so I change the project properties.

[image]

However, once I made this changed the label were gone.

[image]

What I need to do in order of making the label reappear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The map unit size is set respectively to the CRS [units of the layer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/222809/qgis-and-map-units).
I head changed the project CRS, but not the layer CRS.
So, I need to match map unit CRS to the project CRS.
I opened the expression string builder and wrote this function, so the unit map size will be calculated in the "Sphere_Miller_Cylindrical" units.

[image]

This solved the problem and the label reappeared.